# How do i wait for a load of asyncronous pings to all complete in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, networking, ping

I am using the code below to start a load of asyncronous pings. I also have a function which is called by PingCompletedEventHandler, this function adds the address of a successfull ping to a list for use later.

I would like to know how It would be possible to call a function once all of the ping threads have completed?

```
    public static void PingRange(IPRange range)
    {

        foreach (IPAddress ip in range.GetAllIP())
        {
            // Create Pinger
            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pingSender_PingCompleted);

            // Create a 32 byte data buffer
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Wait 4 seconds for a reply
            int timeout = 4000;

            PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

            pingSender.SendAsync(ip, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
            PingStartCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do it with Thread.Join(); method maybe if you put this Method into all Threads that you are supposed to start .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy if you are using .NET 4.0. You can use the `CountdownEvent` class instead of the `PingStartCount` counter and `waiter` event. `CountdownEvent` will perform the job of both.

```
public static void PingRange(IPRange range)
{            
    var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
    foreach (IPAddress ip in range.GetAllIP())
    {
        finished.AddCount(); // Indicate that a new ping is pending
        var pingSender = new Ping();
        pingSender.PingCompleted +=
          (sender, e) =>
          {
            finished.Signal(); // Indicate that this ping is complete
          };
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
        pingSender.SendAsync(ip, 4000, buffer, options, waiter);
    }
    finished.Signal(); // Indicate that all pings have been submitted
    finished.Wait(); // Wait for all pings to complete
}
```

Comment: This solution solved my strange crashes and BSOD's I was getting with the solution below. It did need a slight change however, initialize the countdown event to 1 not 0 and omit the first AddCount. See [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa49f92c-01a8-4901-9846-91bc1587f3ae)

Comment: @leinad13: Yeah, I normally initialize it to 1 as well, but I thought if changed it slightly to include an additional `AddCount` call it would make more sense. I didn't realize that doesn't work. I will edit my answer. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the PingStartCount variable in the pingSender_PingCompleted event handler to track how much pings are still waiting for completion (deduct 1 every time pingSender_PingCompleted is called). Once the PingStartCount reaches 0 you would have recieved all pings back.

However, this is not full proof as you may still be in the process of starting pings, when the counter reaches 0. To make sure this is not the case, a simple bool variable that you set to false at the start of PingRange and to true at the end of PingRange allows you to check if pings are still being send out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, I was part of the way there.. with the PingStartCount variable. The bool value in PingRange was just what I needed.

Comment: Or instead of using a separate `bool` just initialize `PingStartCount` to 1 before the loop, increment it for each ping, decrement it for each completion, and decrement it after the loop. If `PingStartCount` ever reaches 0 then you know that all pings have completed **and** that all were started.

Comment: I implemented the above, and the first debugging session ran fine and did exactly what a wanted. Since then, everytime i try and run the program vshost32.exe crashes at ntdll.dll, then I get a nice BSOD (PROCESS_HAS_LOCKED_PAGES). I tried locking the variables to see if the cross-threads were killing it - but still get a BSOD. Something's gotten corrupt now, as everytime i open the project in VS2010 Program.cs opens in a notepad and is blank. (Wish id backed up)

I'm going to try the solution below next.